# postgresql function text parameter splitting up

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-functions

I have created following postgres function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn(param TEXT)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE param TEXT;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM public."table_name"
    WHERE "column_name" = param;
END
$$
```

where I try to pass a string as parameter :

```
293507407
<class 'str'>
```

but I always run into the following error :

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function fn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM fn('2','9','3','5','0','7','4','0'...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
'''
```

I have tried all possible casting, both in my python code as well as in the function itself.  Without any luck, however.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: How do you call your function ?

Comment: I use :   cursor.callproc(fn, param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `param TEXT` does not need to be repeated in `DECLARE` section as it was already defined as an argument
2. `cursor.callproc(fn, param)` should be `cursor.callproc(fn, [param])`. The way you have it now '293507407' is being taken a sequence of characters e.g. `fn('2','9','3','5','0','7','4','0'...` See [callproc](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=callproc#cursor.callproc) for usage information.
3. Get away from using `callproc`, in psycopg3 it will not exist. Just use `execute` to run the function. This will also work for Postgres procedures which, despite the name, can't be used in `callproc`.

Comment: Actually, I already tried the [param] solution. It doe effectively solve the fn('2','9','3', ...) issue. Unfortunately, it is not being picked up by my query.

Comment: You need to add your query as update to your question, as '...not being picked up by my query.' is not clear.

Comment: Actually I already tried the [param] solution, but it does not get picked up by my function.   My function requires a param values between parenthesis 'param'.                                          I tried adding parenthesis by means of my python code, but that doen'st work either.  Also, quote_literal or quote_ident don't fix th problem.

Comment: here is my original query (outside the function) :                                                                  DELETE FROM public."table_name" WHERE "column_name" = \'param\';

Comment: Please follow instructions and add your queries and explanations to your question so others don't have to work through all the comments to get information. Also have no idea what the `DELETE` query has to do with your question?  FYI, read [SQL parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Show the actual complete query that you use when using `callproc` in your Python code